# Download Multiple PDF files from a webpage

Tags: python, pdf, beautifulsoup, python-requests

So I am trying to download a few eBooks that I have purchased through humble bundle. I am using beautifulsoup and requests to try and parse the html and get the href links for the pdfs.

**Python**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.humblebundle.com/downloads?key=fkuzzq6R8MA8ydEw")


soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "js-all-downloads-holder"})
print(links)
```

I am going to put a imgar link to the site and html layout because I don't believe you can access the html page without prompting a login(Which might be one of the reason I am having this issue to start with.) https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFjWU.jpg

**HTML**

```
<div class="flexbtn active noicon js-start-download">
    <div class="right"></div>
    <span class="label">PDF</span>
        <a class="a" download="" href="https://dl.humble.com/makea2drpginaweekend.pdf?gamekey=fkuzzq6R8MA8ydEw&amp;ttl=1521117317&amp;t=b714bb732413a1f0532ec6aa72b282f9">
            PDF
          </a>
      </div>
```

So the print statement should output to contents of the div but that is not the case.

**Output**

```
python3 pdf_downloader.py 
[]
```

Sorry for the long post, I have just been up all night working on this and at this point it would have just been easier to hit the download button 20+ times but that is not how you learn.

Comment: You need to log in to the page using `requests` before scraping it. You're getting the response that any user would get without logging in.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am going to give selenium a try with this project. Might make it easier.